# Python как разобрать поверхность на грани?

Tags: python, obj

Делаю возможность добавления объекта из obj файла, но рёбра в файл не сохраняются, вопрос: как определить все рёбра объекта зная его поверхности (полигоны), и координаты всех точек объекта? Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот пример obj файла чтобы не искать:

```
mtllib example.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 0.679461 2.566754 -0.679460
v 0.679460 2.566754 0.679461
v -0.679461 2.566754 0.679461
v -0.679461 2.566754 -0.679461
v 0.933361 -0.258484 -0.584207
v 0.933361 -0.258484 0.584207
v 0.746100 1.825238 -0.396945
v 0.746100 1.825238 0.396946
v 3.831785 0.001993 -0.584206
v 3.831785 0.001993 0.584208
v 3.644524 2.085716 -0.396945
v 3.644523 2.085716 0.396947
v 3.719839 1.247650 -0.472261
v 3.716851 1.280893 0.469275
v 5.033208 0.109963 -0.584206
v 5.033208 0.109963 0.584208
v 4.921263 1.355621 -0.472260
v 4.918275 1.388863 0.469275
usemtl Material
s off
f 1 2 3 4
f 5 8 7 6
f 2 1 9 10
f 2 6 7 3
f 3 7 8 4
f 5 1 4 8
f 11 12 16 15
f 6 2 10 12
f 5 6 12 11
f 1 5 11 9
f 17 18 22 21
f 12 10 14 18 16
f 9 11 15 17 13
f 10 9 13 14
f 17 15 16 18
f 19 21 22 20
f 14 13 19 20
f 18 14 20 22
f 13 17 21 19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтение obj файла особого труда не составляет: достаточно читать его построчно, добавляя числа из строки в список координат вершин, если строка начинается на `v`, или в список индексов вершин, принадлежащих одной грани, если строка начинается на `f`. Остальные строки в рамках данной задачи можно игнорировать.

Предположим, что вы уже прочитали файл, и у вас есть два списка - `v` с координатами вершин и `f` со списками вершин, образующих грань:

```
>>> v
[(1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000), (1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000), ...]

>>> f
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 8, 7, 6), ...]
```

Чтобы определить рёбра, нужно взять все пары индексов вершин из `f` и сопоставить их с координатами из `v`. Для начала нужно преобразовать каждый элемент из `f` в список пар:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4) -> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Первый и последний элемент также образуют пару. Разбить список (кортеж) на пары можно таким однострочником:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> zip(a[:-1], a[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Чтобы первый и последний элемент образовывали пару, можно добавить в конец списка (кортежа) первый элемент.

Пары вершин складываем в `set`, чтобы устранять дубликаты. Важно помнить, что ребро не имеет направления, и `(1, 2)` и `(2, 1)` - это одно и то же ребро. Поэтому имеет смысл перед помещением элемента в `set` сортировать его:

```
>>> e1 = [2, 1]
>>> e2 = [1, 2]
>>> e = set()
# используем кортеж, так как список - unhashable, и поэтому его нельзя хранить в set
>>> e.add(tuple(sorted(e1)))
>>> e.add(tuple(sorted(e2)))
>>> e
{(1, 2)}
```

Теперь, имея на руках множество пар индексов вершин, соединённых рёбрами, можно сопоставить их с координатами, и получить список координат концов рёбер. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
>>> def coord(i, j):
...     return (v[i-1], v[j-1])
...
>>> map(lambda z: coord(*z), e)
[(0.1, 0.2), ...]
```

P.S. В Python 3 (который я использовал для написания примера) функции `map` и `zip` (а также ряд других функций, обрабатывающих коллекции) возвращают не список, а итератор. Его можно использовать везде, где предполагается перечисляемое множество (iterable). Однако, для отображения его в читаемом виде (а не в виде, например, `<map object at 0x00279F50>`) нужно явно привести его к нужному типу:

```
>>> map(lambda z: coord(*z), e)
<map object at 0x00279F50>
>>> list(map(lambda z: coord(*z), e))
[(0.1, 0.2), ...]
```

Для лучшей читабельности эти приведения я в примерах кода опустил.